# UPDATE a whole row in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, plpgsql

I have plpgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
    my_row my_table%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO my_row FROM my_table WHERE id='1';
    my_row.date := now();
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I would like to know if it's possible to directly UPDATE `my_row` record.

The only way I've found to do it now is:

```
UPDATE my_table SET date=now() WHERE id='1';
```

Note this is only an example function, the real one is far more complex than this.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.

UPDATE:

Sorry for the confusion, what I wanted to say is:

```
SELECT * INTO my_row FROM my_table INTO my_row WHERE id='1';
make_lots_of_complicated_modifications_to(my_row, other_complex_parameters);
UPDATE my_row;
```

I.e. Use my_`row` to persist information in the underlying table. I have lots of parameters to update.

Comment: Why don't you select NOW() in the first place, instead of a vague * ?

Comment: Do you want to update the variable in your plpgsql function or the row in the underlying table?

Comment: I want to persist the variable into the table without having to rewrite a field-by-field query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would like to know if it's possible to directly update "my_row"
>   record.

It is.
You can update columns of a row or record type in plpgsql - just like you have it. It should be working, obviously?

This would update the underlying table, of course, not the variable!

```
UPDATE my_table SET date=now() WHERE id='1';
```

You are confusing two things here ...

---

#### Answer to clarification in comment

I don't think there is syntax in PostgreSQL that can `UPDATE` a whole row. You can [**`UPDATE` a column list**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html), though. Consider this demo:

Note how I use `thedate` instead of `date` as column name, `date` is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in every SQL standard and a type name in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE my_table (id serial, thedate date);
INSERT INTO my_table(thedate) VALUES (now());

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_up()
  RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
    _r my_table;
BEGIN
   SELECT * INTO _r FROM my_table WHERE id = 1;
   _r.thedate := now()::date + 5 ;

   UPDATE my_table t
    -- explicit list of columns to be to updated
   SET   (id, thedate) = (_r.id, _r.thedate)
   WHERE  t.id = 1;
END
$func$;

SELECT test_up();
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

However, you can **[`INSERT` a whole row](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html)** easily. Just don't supply a column list for the table (which you normally should, but in this case it is perfectly ok, not to).

As an `UPDATE` is internally a `DELETE` followed by an `INSERT` anyway, and a function automatically encapsulates everything in a transaction, I don't see, why you couldn't use this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION x.test_ delins()
  RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
    _r my_table;
BEGIN
   SELECT * INTO _r
   FROM my_table WHERE id = 1;
   _r.thedate := now()::date + 10;

   DELETE FROM my_table t WHERE t.id = 1;
   INSERT INTO my_table SELECT _r.*;
END
$func$;
```

Comment: How could I persist the ROWTYPE variable directly?

Comment: Do you want to `UPDATE` the whole row or just the one column?

Comment: The whole row, I'm changing lots of fields with complex calculations. It would be something like oracle's SET ROW.

Comment: Erwin...  it seems like the problem with the delete/insert method would be issues with foreign keys.  How would/could you over come those issues?

Comment: @DavidS: Foreign keys pointing to the table would prohibit the DELETE/INSERT workaround. You *could* use dynamic SQL to generate a long list of columns for the `UPDATE` from the system catalog, in particular [`pg_attribute`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-attribute.html) ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I was playing around with this more this morning because I have a similar need right now.  Changing the foreign key to be deferrable and then calling "SET CONSTRAINTS somename_fkey DEFERRED;" at the beginning of the procedure seems to work for me.  I might post my code and see if anyone can suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get this working in PLPGSQL in a couple of lines of code.

Given a table called `table` in a schema called `example`, and a record of the same type declared as `_record`, you can update all the columns in the table to match the record using the following hack:

```
declare _record example.table;

...

-- get the columns in the correct order, as a string
select string_agg(format('%I', column_name), ',' order by ordinal_position)
  into _columns
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_schema='example' and table_name='table';

execute 'update example.table set (' || _columns || ') = row($1.*) where pkey=$2'
  using _record, _record.pkey;
```

In the above example, of course, `_record.pkey` is the table's primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql has not set row in update.
If you wont update full row you should assign value for each column separately

Answer (score 0):

yes, its possible to update / append the row-type variable,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE    
         my_row my_table%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
         SELECT * INTO my_row FROM my_table WHERE id='1';
         my_row.date := now(); 
         raise notice  'date  : %; ',my_row.date;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

here the raise notice will display the today's date only.

but this will not update the column date in my_table.

Comment: I know, the date was an example, I'm making lots of changes into my_row and I want an easy way to persist the information again without having to write an UPDATE my_table SET <lots of changes> WHERE id=my_row.id. I think Oracle has a SET ROW system to persist records with these structures.