# How to remove values from an array that exist in another array?

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql

In PostgreSQL I have a table (`Table`) that contains an id column (`ID`) and another column (`Values`) that contains an array of strings. I have a select query (`SelectQuery`) that gets me an `ID` that matches `Table.ID`, as well as an array of values (`RemoveValues`). I would like to now remove from the `Values` array, any strings that are contained in the `RemoveValues` array that match on `ID`, updating Table.

```sql
--Table--

ID            Values
--  ----------------------------
1   {string1, string2, string3}
2   {string1, string2, string3}
...

--SelectQuery--

ID          RemoveValues
--  ----------------------------
1   {string2}
2   {string1, string2}
...
```

***Execute query that I can't figure out***

```sql
--Table--

ID            Values
--  ----------------------------
1   {string1, string3}
2   {string3}
...
```

I can't seem to figure out a good way to do this, I've played with a number of joins and the sql array methods and haven't found anything that works. Is there's a way to loop the `remove()` method for each element in `RemoveValues`? I've also tried something like this with no luck:

```
select array_agg(elem)
from Table, unnest(Table.Values) elem
where elem <> all(
    SelectQuery )
);
```

I'm feeling like my remaining option is a bash script, unless anyone can suggest a path forward using SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways.

First, you have to define whether there can be **duplicates** or **`NULL`** values in either of the arrays - and how to deal with those if possible. And whether to preserve original **order of elements**.

Assuming either is possible, and these are the rules:

- Count duplicates separately. So if `Values` has five elements 'foo' and  `RemoveValues` has three elements 'foo', thee will be two element 'foo' in the result.
- Treat `NULL` values equal. So `NULL` can be removed with `NULL` (though in other contexts `NULL = NULL` yields `NULL`).
- Order of array elements does not have to be preserved.
- `<SelectQuery>` produces unique `ID` values.

That matches the behavior of standard SQL [`EXCEPT ALL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-EXCEPT). See:

- [Using EXCEPT clause in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329419/using-except-clause-in-postgresql/35329553#35329553)

So:

```sql
SELECT t.*, sub.result_array
FROM   tbl t
JOIN   (<SelectQuery>) s USING ("ID")
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT unnest(t."Values")
      EXCEPT ALL
      SELECT unnest(s."RemoveValues")
      )
   ) sub(result_array);
```

About the `LATERAL` subquery:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Can be plain `CROSS JOIN` because an [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) always produces a row.

You could wrap the functionality in a custom function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f_arr_except_arr(a1 text[], a2 text[])
  RETURNS text[]
  LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE
BEGIN ATOMIC
SELECT ARRAY (SELECT unnest(a1) EXCEPT ALL SELECT unnest(a2));
END;
```

Requires Postgres 14. See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC ... END mean in a Postgresql SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300512/3684)

For older (or *any*) Postgres versions, and for *any* array type:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_arr_except_arr(a1 anyarray, a2 anyarray)
  RETURNS anyarray
  LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY (SELECT unnest(a1) EXCEPT ALL SELECT unnest(a2));
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1a43aa13056ae0075748d114bf26daf8)*

(`PARALLEL SAFE` only for Postgres 9.6 or later, though.)

Then your query can be something like:

```sql
SELECT *, f_arr_except_arr(t."Values", s."RemoveValues") AS result_values
FROM   tbl t
JOIN  (<SelectQuery>) s USING ("ID");
```

It's unclear whether you actually locked in CaMeL-case spelling with double-quotes. I assumed as much, but better you don't. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

And your **`UPDATE`** can be:

```sql
UPDATE tbl t
SET    "Values" = f_arr_except_arr(t."Values", s."RemoveValues")
FROM   <SelectQuery>) s
WHERE  s."ID" = t."ID"
AND    "Values" IS DISTINCT FROM f_arr_except_arr(t."Values", s."RemoveValues");
```

The additional `WHERE` clause is optional to avoid empty updates. See:

- [Return rows of a table that actually changed in an UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956089/return-rows-of-a-table-that-actually-changed-in-an-update/27958268#27958268)
- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Comment: Erwin, as always you're a SQL legend. This answer was perfect and got me exactly what I needed. Un-nesting the array to remove values was brilliant, thank you!