# Postgres plpgsql - ARRAY record attribute asssignment

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Will appreciate if someone can please guide if Postgres allows assignment for a ARRAY record attribute. For example - dummy set up.

Trying to update an ttribute of a Record (part of array) .
The direct assignment does not work. Have to create a roundabout way of creating extra record, assignment and swapping.

```
 create table dummy_array (id numeric, descr varchar(100));
 insert into dummy_array values(1,'TEST1'),(2,'TEST2');
 select * from dummy_array;
 do
  $function$
   declare
    v_array dummy_array[];
    v_dummy_rec dummy_array;
       begin
        v_array=array(select ROW(id,descr) from dummy_array);
         raise notice '%',v_array[1].descr; 
         --FOLLOWING DIRECT ASSIGNMENT DOES NOT WORK
         v_array[1].descr :='ZZZ';--This assignment errors out 
         end ;
   $function$

      Errors out with SQL ERROR[42601]:ERROR:syntax error at or near "."
      Tried even  (v_array[1]).descr :='ZZZ'; does not work
```

Following Works but a hack create temp, copy,assign ,modify reassing

```
         do
         $function$
          declare
           v_array dummy_array[];
           v_dummy_rec dummy_array;
         begin
           v_array=array(select ROW(id,descr) from dummy_array);
           raise notice '%',v_array[1].descr;   
           **--v_array[1].descr :='ZZZ';--This assignment errors out**
           v_dummy_rec :=v_array[1];
           v_dummy_rec.descr :='ZZZ';
           v_array[1]:=v_dummy_rec;
           raise notice '%',v_array[1].descr;   
          end ;
         $function$
```

Can somone please guide me if it is possible to do direct assignments like shown above

```
        **v_array[1].descr :='ZZZ';--This assignment errors out**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `v_array` has the type `dummy_array[]`, so it will only  accept a `dummy_array[]` value.

This works `v_array[1] := ROW(1,'ZZZ');`

```
 do
  $function$
   declare
    v_array dummy_array[];
    v_dummy_rec dummy_array;
       begin
        v_array=array(select ROW(id,descr) from dummy_array);
         raise notice '%',v_array[1].descr; 
         v_array[1] := ROW(1,'ZZZ'); 
        raise notice '%',v_array[1].descr; 
         end ;
   $function$
```

**Answer to clarificate comment**

In PostgreSQL it is possible to update individual attributes of a record ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12529485/8379001)). In your case the problem is the array, there is where PostgreSQL fails; because it seems it doesn't compile the `v_array[1]` as a record variable when running the code (PL), it just see it as an array element (therefore the error message). This can be "fixed" using an extra variable of type `dummy_array` without the array; that is your `v_dummy_rec`:

```
DO $function$
DECLARE
    v_array dummy_array[];
    v_dummy_rec dummy_array;
BEGIN
    v_array=array(select ROW(id,descr) from dummy_array);
      raise notice '%',v_array[1].descr; 
    v_array[1] := ROW(1,'ZZZ'); 
      raise notice '%',v_array[1].descr;
-- Here is the use of v_dummy_rec:
    v_dummy_rec := v_array[1];
    v_dummy_rec.descr := 'AAA';
    v_array[1] := v_dummy_rec;
      raise notice '%',v_array[1].descr;
END; $function$
```

The `RAISE NOTICE` outputs:

```
NOTICE:  TEST1
NOTICE:  ZZZ
NOTICE:  AAA
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry , my question was not clear. My question stems from Oracle to postgres migration. Oracle allows an individual attribure of a record(which is part of array to be updated).  assignments like v_array[1].descr :='ZZZ';    are valid where as Postgres did not allow. Wanted to know if such attribute assignment are note allowed  and the whole record need to be updated vs it is an issue with my syntax and some alternate syntax exists. In my case record struture is wide and only very small subset of attribute need update as we go over the array iteratively .

Comment: Updated my answer for clarification.